# Creating a video sitemap for YouTube embedded videos

Tags: xml, video, iframe, youtube, sitemap

So I have a website in which I have plenty of YouTube videos embedded using their default iframes. Now, I want to create a video sitemap for my website, but I can't seem to find a clear guide on how to do it with videos inside frames. [This entry](https://moz.com/blog/video-sitemap-guide-for-vimeo-and-youtube) from the Moz.com blog says that you need to use YouTube's old embed code (the one using `<object>` tags) in order for robots to be able to crawl them, as they don't crawl iframes. However, it's almost 5 years old (January 2012). So I looked at [this other link](http://www.audiencebloom.com/google-known-crawl-iframes-website/) from AudienceBloom.com which claims that Google does crawl iframes now, as long as they're SEO-friendly(?). However, it adds that:

> it is suspect that Google, unlike other major search engines, will ignore iFrames that point to a different domain, and not the top-level domain, or TDL.

but, again, this article isn't very recent. It's over 2 years old in fact.

So my question is, what is the current situation of this matter? Would google now crawl videos inside YouTube iframes as long as they're properly included in the sitemap? Or would I have to use either the `<noframes>` tag or the old YouTube embed code?

Any help would be widely appreciated! and I'm sure this will also be of help to a lot of other people, given how unclear this matter seems to be right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like in the comment from **w3dk** of [THIS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/92388) post written it seems that google IS indexing the Iframes just maybe *not* within the context of the parent document.
(2016)

[At support.google.com](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34445?hl=en&vid=0-281984168833-1485025279398) you can find that "Google tries to associate framed content with the page containing the frames, but we don't guarantee that we will."

But the more information you give, the better it is.
So I would recommend to make a sitemap as well as adding the `<noframes>` for those who've disabled frames. (to provide alternate content)

Comment: The entries you linked were helpful and pointed me in the right direction :) Thanks!